# VBA to select list in IE

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to use VBA to open an IE window and select from one of the dropdown list showing bwin but failed. Any advice?

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
.Silent = True
.Visible = True
.Navigate "http://www.yahoo.com/"
End With

While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

Set AvailableLinks = oIE.document.getelementbyid("list-listing").getelementsbytagname("a")

    For Each cLink In AvailableLinks
        If cLink.innerhtml = "????" Then
            cLink.Click
        End If
    Next cLink
End Sub
```

Comment: Although this is not what you asked, I once circumvented this by setting the value of the element to what I wanted

Comment: Hi Moacir. Thanks for writing back. Care to elaborate?

Comment: instead of using `cLink.Click` I used something like `cLink.Value = <What would be selected>`

Comment: It's failing because the object with id "list-listing" doesn't exist in the webpage (by the way, you're having a "o" in front of your "ie" object when you make the set. What is that you're exactly trying to click? How can a non-Chinese speaker locate what you're trying to select?

Comment: Other problem that I see in your code, is you're trying to say "if innerHTML = "????"". That's the result of writing Chinese characters directly in the code (the code can't hold them): you will want to write them somewhere in a  range and then make something like "if innerHtml = Range("yourValue")"